# Питон. Как остановить функцию при наступлении какого либо события

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyttsx3

Добрый день сегодня у меня возникла проблема.
мне нужно завершить работу одной функции другой, возможно ли это, пойдут любые методы

```
import pyttsx3
import asyncio


def stop_fun():
    # Здесь должен быть код который остановит функцию play_text
    pass


def play_text(text):
    try:
        engine = pyttsx3.init()
        engine.setProperty('rate', 150)
        engine.say(text)
        engine.runAndWait()  # Мне нужно остановить эту строку при наступления 
        # события
    except KeyError:
        pass


play_text("Привет как дела")
```

две функции будут работать параллельно и когда в первой происходит событие, то вторая функция должна остановиться

Comment: Можно конечно придумать минимум три костыля. Но не понятно, почему нельзя менять код исходной функции... и где именно и как она вызывается, чтобы её "правильно" остановить. Ну можно сделать `def stop_fun(): pyttsx3.runAndWait = lambda: ...`

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME можете по подробнее рассказать про эти костыли

Comment: создавать отдельный процесс, запускать в нем функцию и убивать его при необходимости: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752174/2764727. удобнее так делать с потоком, но я не нашел как это делать, может кто знает.

Answer (score 0):

```
def stop_fan():
    raise KeyError
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]